# Entity Framework Code First - Can I hide a database field from the model?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'm trying to create a clean model using EF 4.3 Code first. I know enums are not fully supported until EF 5.0.

To get around this I've been trying to do something like this:

```
public class Vehicle {
   public VehicleId int { get;set; }
   public VehicleType VehicleType 
   { 
      get  { return (VehicleType)VehicleTypeId; } 
   }
   internal VehicleTypeId int { get; set; }  
}
```

So I wish to store the vehicleTypeId in the database but just show the enum in the model

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work. The vehicleTypeId didn't get created in the db.

Comment: Is the property visible to your context?

Comment: No it's not, I thought perhaps I could of mapped VehicleTypeId using the fluent API but it's not visible in the context. Perhaps if it were in the same assembly it would be but I need to separate the model from the data access.

Answer (score 0):

If your property is not visible to the context, it will not be mapped. You can use a trick described [here](http://blog.cincura.net/232731-mapping-private-protected-properties-in-entity-framework-4-x-code-first/) to make your internal properties available for mapping.

Comment: Thanks, it's a nice little hack but it would just be re-exposing the underlying internal properties through an additional static method. Where this is an improvement, I'd have to do this every time I had an enum to keep a / semi clean model and it wouldn't be truly clean.

Comment: It is the cleanest approach you can get with EF code first except using `InternalsVisibleTo` and allowing your DAL assembly access to internal properties of entity assembly.